# How can I create a countdown from a Date().getTime() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, ionic-framework, timer, countdown

I have an click function who get a number from Date().getTime(). I want to take this number and convert him in a countdown on my view.

I'm using only javascript with Ionic framework 1x.

```
var currentDate = new Date().getTime();
console.log(currentDate);

var secondDate = new Date(item.date).getTime();
console.log(secondDate);
secondDate = new Date(secondDate).getSeconds();
console.log(secondDate);
$scope.countdown = secondDate;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain JavaScript you can make use of `setInterval` like this:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  console.log(new Date().getTime());
}, 1000);
```

In Ionic/Angular, you'll need to replace `setInterval` with the wrapper [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval):

```
$interval(function() {
  $scope.countdown = new Date().getTime();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you czosel! It's worked perfectly. About the time, there is a simple way to reverse the countdown ?

Comment: You're welcome! To reverse the countdown, you could calculate the difference between the current date and the date you're counting down to, and bind that value to the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
$scope.countdown -= 1;
    if ($scope.countdown == 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
},1000);
```